# Group properties into classes and map them to the same table as root class in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have an entity with hundreds of properties. While it is good in database, in classes it is inconvenient. The question is, how can I group some properties of the class into other classes so it would be more convenient in programming, while keeping only one table.

Pseudocode example:

```
class Work {
 WorkVolumes WorkVolumes;
 ...
 SomeOtherGroupOfProperties SomeOtherGroup;
}

class WorkVolumes {
 float VolumeOfWorkType1;
 float VolumeOfWorkType2;
 ...
 float VolumeEtc;
}

class SomeOtherGroupOfProperties {
 int SomeOtherProperty;
 ...
}
```

While in database there is only table Work with columns VolumeOfWorkType1, VolumeOfWorkType2, VolumeEtc, SomeOtherProperty, ...

Comment: You're looking for `Complex Types`. Not sure whether it's implemented already or not.

Comment: @haim770 thanks for the comment, it helped me to get to the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see "Automatic table splitting for owned entity types" here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/06/28/announcing-ef-core-2-0-preview-2/

> for the following model only one table is created:
>
> ```
> modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().OwnsOne(
>     p => p.OrderDetails,
>     cb =>
>     {
>         cb.OwnsOne(c => c.BillingAddress);
>         cb.OwnsOne(c => c.ShippingAddress);
>     });
>
> public class Order
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public OrderDetails OrderDetails { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class OrderDetails
> {
>     public StreetAddress BillingAddress { get; set; }
>     public StreetAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class StreetAddress
> {
>     public string Street { get; set; }
>     public string City { get; set; }
> }
> ```